# Hausdorff measurment - unit tests

Tags: java, matlab, unit-testing, opencv, image-processing

I wrote an implementation to calculate the Hausdorff distance of 2 pictures, and now I would like to write a unit test. The general idea is to generate synthetic pictures with known Hausdorff distance, but I'm not sure what the pseudo-code should look like.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What language are you programming in? If you add a language tag you're likely to get more views.

Comment: thanks, i added. though pseudo code is good enough

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the 2nd question (for tools/API), which is [not permitted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I hope this is OK for you.

Comment: The Hausdorff distance is defined between sets. How did you implement this for images? Are you using binary images, and computing the spatial distance between foreground pixels? Or is this some sort of grey-value distance or grey-weighted spatial distance? Please clarify what you implemented!